# Unable to run bash resource in Chef Recipe

Tags: bash, shell, chef-infra

I am running a bash resource in chef which is giving the error cp not found.

```
bash 'Copy Contents recursively' do
  cwd '/home/abc'
  command "cp -r * /home/def"
  user 'alpha'
  group 'alpha'
  environment('HOME' => '/home/alpha',
              'USER' => 'alpha'
             )
end
```

I have also noticed that none of the bash commands are working and I always receive a command not found error.

Comment: 1. You are not using the "bash" resource 2. this action is not idempotent 3. cwd and HOME are different 4. Chef provides a nice error message on failures which would have been helpful to answer the question

Comment: I do not understand point number 3. I am just changing the directory to /home/abc. Also the execute part was a typing mistake,

Comment: Try to provide a full path to cp command, like `/usr/bin/cp`. I think PATH is not set inside the resource by default.

Comment: Yes that happened to be the correct solution..i have set the path variables using ENV command! Thank you!